My elements (innerHTML) goes out of Container. How to prevent it?
I have a registration form.
Container form - and inside div elements (login/email)
Height and Width are constant (width: 90%, height: 440px)
And have <div class="error"> element - where i "innerHTML' error message.
But when it inserts  error it goes out of Container.
Click "SIGN UP" - the container size doesn't stretch (
How to stretch container to its new size with messages ?
You can run code here: https://jsfiddle.net/krekercod4/ojzambrv/1/


function userRegister(){
    let emailField = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let passField = document.getElementById("password").value;
    let fullNameField = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    let phoneField = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
    

    let person = {
        email: emailField,
        password: passField,
        fullName: fullNameField,
        phoneNumber: phoneField,
    };

    
    //let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UsersVK")) || [];
    if(emailField==""){
        emailDiv.innerHTML="Please inter Email";
    }
    if(passField==""){
        passDiv.innerHTML="Please inter password";
    }
    if(fullNameField==""){
        fullNameDiv.innerHTML="Please inter full name";
    }
    if(phoneField==""){
        phoneDiv.innerHTML="Please inter phone number";
    }

    else{users.push(person);

    //localStorage.setItem("UsersVK",JSON.stringify(users));
    alert("User saved successfully");}


}
.right{
    background-color: #222222;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.right-authorization{
    width: 90%;
    height: 440px;
    border: 1px solid  #363738;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 8px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: visible;
   
    
}

.sign-in{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 6px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}


.login-outside {
    background-color: #222222;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid  #363738;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
}


.login-write{
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
}
.login-write input{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
}

.login-write input:focus{
    border-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}


.inside{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.login{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.login button{
    background-color: #5e8abe;
    border: 1px solid  #363738;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 110px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.login button:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}


.register-text{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.register-text a{
    text-decoration: underline rgb(193, 193, 193);
    color: white;
}

.register-text a:hover{
    color: #7a7a7a;
}

.invalid {
    color: #ff2748;
    border-color: #ff2748;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
<div class="right">
    <form class="right-authorization">
          <div class="sign-in">
            <i class='bx bx-user bx-sm'></i>
            SIGN-UP
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="login one-container">
            <div class="login-outside" >
                <div class="login-write">
                    <i class='bx bx-user bx-xs'></i>
                    <input class="inside" type="text" placeholder="email" id="email" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="emailDiv" class="invalid"></div>

            <div class="login-outside">
                <div class="password login-write">
                    <i class='bx bx-lock-alt bx-xs'></i>
                    <input class="inside" type="password" placeholder="password" minlength="6" id="password">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="passDiv" class="invalid"></div>

            <div class="login-outside">
                <div class="name-surname login-write">
                    <i class='bx bx-edit-alt bx-xs'></i>
                    <input class="inside" type="text" placeholder="full name" id="fullName">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fullNameDiv" class="invalid"></div>
            
            <div class="login-outside">
                <div class="number login-write">
                    <i class='bx bx-phone bx-xs'></i>
                    <input class="inside" type="text" placeholder="phone number" id="phoneNumber">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="phoneDiv" class="invalid"></div>

            <button type="button" onclick="userRegister()">Sign up</button>
              <div class="register-text">
                  <span>Already have an account ? <br><a href="web-site_login.html">Sign in</a></span>
              </div>
          </div>
    </form>
</div>



Wanna stretch container to new size after inserting "innerHTML".
I am new at HTML/CSS.

Why do you need to set the height to 440? leave it to be auto.

Consider avoiding fixed width and height for elements.
Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mdhasanpatwary/sefn7z6p/3/


function userRegister(){
    let emailField = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let passField = document.getElementById("password").value;
    let fullNameField = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    let phoneField = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
    

    let person = {
        email: emailField,
        password: passField,
        fullName: fullNameField,
        phoneNumber: phoneField,
    };

    
    let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UsersVK")) || [];
    if(emailField==""){
        emailDiv.innerHTML="Please inter Email";
    }
    if(passField==""){
        passDiv.innerHTML="Please inter password";
    }
    if(fullNameField==""){
        fullNameDiv.innerHTML="Please inter full name";
    }
    if(phoneField==""){
        phoneDiv.innerHTML="Please inter phone number";
    }

    else{users.push(person);

    localStorage.setItem("UsersVK",JSON.stringify(users));
    alert("User saved successfully");}


}
.right{
    background-color: #222222;
    border-radius: 12px;
    max-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.right-authorization{
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid  #363738;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 8px;
    margin-block: 15px;
   
    
}

.sign-in{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 6px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}


.login-outside {
    background-color: #222222;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid  #363738;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
}


.login-write{
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
}
.login-write input{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.login-write input:focus{
    border-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}


.inside{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.login{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.login button{
    background-color: #5e8abe;
    border: 1px solid  #363738;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 110px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.login button:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}


.register-text{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.register-text a{
    text-decoration: underline rgb(193, 193, 193);
    color: white;
}

.register-text a:hover{
    color: #7a7a7a;
}

.invalid {
    color: #ff2748;
    border-color: #ff2748;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
<div class="right">
    <form class="right-authorization">
          <div class="sign-in">
            <i class='bx bx-user bx-sm'></i>
            SIGN-UP
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="login one-container">
            <div class="login-outside" >
                <div class="login-write">
                    <i class='bx bx-user bx-xs'></i>
                    <input class="inside" type="text" placeholder="email" id="email" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="emailDiv" class="invalid"></div>

            <div class="login-outside">
                <div class="password login-write">
                    <i class='bx bx-lock-alt bx-xs'></i>
                    <input class="inside" type="password" placeholder="password" minlength="6" id="password">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="passDiv" class="invalid"></div>

            <div class="login-outside">
                <div class="name-surname login-write">
                    <i class='bx bx-edit-alt bx-xs'></i>
                    <input class="inside" type="text" placeholder="full name" id="fullName">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fullNameDiv" class="invalid"></div>
            
            <div class="login-outside">
                <div class="number login-write">
                    <i class='bx bx-phone bx-xs'></i>
                    <input class="inside" type="text" placeholder="phone number" id="phoneNumber">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="phoneDiv" class="invalid"></div>

            <button type="button" onclick="userRegister()">Sign up</button>
              <div class="register-text">
                  <span>Already have an account ? <br><a href="web-site_login.html">Sign in</a></span>
              </div>
          </div>
    </form>
</div>




you can remove the fixed height from the .right-authorization class and let it adjust automatically based on its content.
.right-authorization {
width: 90%;
border: 1px solid #363738;
border-radius: 12px;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
color: white;
padding: 5px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
font-weight: 400;
justify-content: center;
gap: 8px;
margin-top: 15px;
overflow: hidden;

}
